# SQL Server - Oracle Linked Server with join

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008, join, linked-server, openquery

Hare is the scenario:

Main DB Server: SQL Server 2008 R2 with a Linked Server to Oracle 11g.

I have a Stored Procedure that make a query like:

```
Select t1.a, t1.b, t2.c, t3.d
From LocalTable a inner join LinkedServerName..Schema.Tableb b on a.aNumber= b.id
     inner join LinkedServerName..Schema.Tablec c on b.value = c.id
     inner join LinkedServerName..Schema.Tabled d on a.someOtherNumber = d.Id
 Where a.WhereValue1 = @Parameter1
   and b.WhereValue2 = @Parameter2
```

That turns to be painfully slow. I cannot figure out how use OpenQuery to improve the query since the *Where* clauses uses parameters (if that is even possible to use).

Is there way to improve the data Retrieval? I'm retrieving millions of records from the Oracle DB.

Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest you do is at least create a view on the Oracle side that joins tables b,c,d and join to that view. How many records are in LocalTable? If there are very few (under 10,000 or so) then you are better joining the entire thing on the Oracle side.

What is your overall objective? Are you building a report or trying to identifying differing records so you can merge the data? Are you able to make changes on the oracle side?